# Add single word attribute to dom element in C#

Tags: c#, dom, microdata

I'm implementing microdata on site built in C#. The desired wrapper div for a product should look like this:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Product">
```

It's easy to add the **itemtype** attribute like below

```
domElement.Attributes["itemtype"] = "http://data-vocabulary.org/Product";
```

But I have no idea how can I add a single word attribute like **itemscope**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, attributes tend to require values with many libraries. Most people will get around this by writing something like `itemscope=true` or `itemscope=""`.
EDIT: Reworded when I found that some XML implementations do use blank attributes without any issues.

Comment: This is only true for XHTML, other forms would treat a non-valued attribute as a boolean. A non-valued `itemscope` attrib is what is expected for microdata.

Comment: Apologies, did not know this. I've always encountered that some 'fluff' data is necessary for many XML libraries implementation of attributes.